# Form in Joomla website to run script

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I'm new to Joomla and quite newbie to websites in general.

I want to provide the user a form with a couple of text-input widgets and some check-buttons. After the user fill them and hit the "Submit" button I want to run a (python) script in the background. The script will collect some data from the internet and make a specific plot. The plot is embebed in a HTML document (I'm using Bokeh here), which I should present back to the user.
 And I need some help to figure out how to do it.

Doubt number 1: I saw that there are some Form extensions around (e.g, Form Maker), but do I need them?
Doubt number 2: How do I trigger the execution of a (python) script on my system, wait for its return and access the output (let's say output is called 'plot.html')
Doubt number 3: The output (plot.html), should I present it on a new tab of the user's client or may I embed at this point in the page where the form is (below the form, for example)?

Thank you

Comment: Take a look at [BreezingForms](https://crosstec.org/en/breezingforms-lite-download.html) It helped me A LOT with creating forms in Joomla.

Answer (score 0):

You could start by creating a small [Joomla module](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Creating_a_simple_module/Developing_a_Basic_Module). In its `tmpl/default.php` file, just create the form in HTML as you would with any other form - have the form submit to itself.

In the module's entry point `mod_mymodule.php`, use a conditional to check the form has been submitted, then use one of [PHP's program executions functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.exec.php), such as exec, to run your Python code, passing in the needed variables.

Finally display the your output HTML in `tmpl/default.php` passing it as a variable in from `mod_mymodule.php`.